# Fooling Around With Databases, Online Development

Tags: database, database-design

I'm trying to design a database for a small project I'm working on.  Eventually, I'd like to make it a web-app, but right now I don't mind just experimenting with data offline. However, I'm stuck in a crossroads.

The basic concept would be a user inputs values for 10 fields, to be compared against what is in the database, with each item having a weighted value.  I know that if I was to code it, that I could use a look-up tables for each field, add up the values, and display the result to the end-user.

Another example would be having to get the distance between two points, each point stored in a row, with the X value getting its own column as well as the Y value.

Now, if I store data within a database, should I try to do everything within queries (which I think would involve temporary tables among other things), or just use simple queries, and manipulate the rows returned within the application code?

Right now, I'm thinking to go for the latter (manipulate data within the app) and just use queries to reduce the amount of data that I would have to go sort through.  What would you guys suggest?

EDIT: Right now I'm using Microsoft Access to get the basics down pat and try to get a good design going.  IIRC with my experience with Oracle and MySQL you can run commands together in a batch process and return just one result.  But not sure if you can do that with Access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a database I would strongly suggest using SQL to do all your manipulation. SQL is far more capable and powerful for this kind of job as compared to imperative programming languages.

Of course it does imply that you're comfortable in thinking about data as "sets" and programming in a declarative style. But spending time now to get really comfortable with SQL and manipulating data using SQL will pay off big time in the long run. Not only for this project but for projects in the future. I would also suggest using stored procedures over queries in code because stored procedure provide a beautiful abstraction layer allowing your table design to change over time without impacting the rest of the system.

A very big part of using and working with databases is understanding Data modeling, normalization and the like. Like everything else it will be a effort but in the long run it will pay off.

May I ask why you're using Access when you have a far better database available to you such as MSSQL Express? The migration path from MSSQL Express to MSSQL or SQL Azure even is quite seamless and everything you do and experience today (in this project) completely translates to MSSQL Server/SQL Azure for future projects as well as if this project grows beyond your expectations.

I don't understand your last statement about running a batch process and getting just one result, but if you can do it in Oracle and MySQL then you can do it in MSSQL Express as well.

Comment: I have Access on my PC for basic testing, and VS2008 without SQL Express. I don't want to lock myself into a specific database, or programming language with this project.  I'm leaning towards Asp.Net, but I'd rather get the core concepts working with the back-end before doing anything else.

Comment: @Jeffery so what you're saying is Access doesn't tie you to a specific database? Or MSSQL ties you to a specific programming language? All I'm saying is that the core concepts are easier to get and implement in a Database engine that is more mainstream so you can migrate to other databases if need be. Databases have nothing to do with programming languages and I don't believe I even mentioned programming languages (since you didn't either)

Comment: Valid point.  I'm downloading the latest version of Visual Studio Express right now.

Comment: @Jeffery, I was talking about MSSQL Express 2008 not VS. Sorry , didn't mean to confuse you. Here is the link to download it. You'll have to choose between 32/64 bit and the version with or without tools. I suggest the version that says "Database with Management tool". That's the third option from the left

Comment: Haha, I needed to update everything anyway.  I have Web Developer 2010 now (with VB.Net as well) and SQL Server Express 2008.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What Shiv said, and also...

A good DBMS has quite a bit of solid engineering in it.  There are two components that are especially carefully engineered, namely the query optimizer and the transaction controller.  If you adopt the view of using the DBMS as just a stupid table retrieval tool, you will most likely end up inventing your own optimizer and transaction controller inside the application.  You won't need the transaction controller until you move to an environment that supports multiple concurrent users.

Unless your engineering talents are extraordinary, you will probably end up with a home brew data management system that is not as good as the one in a good DBMS.

The learning curve for SQL is steep.  You need to learn how to phrase queries that join, project, and restrict data from multiple tables.  You need to learn how to handle updates in the context of a transaction.

You need to learn simple and sound table design and index design.  This includes, but is not limited to, data normalization and data modeling. And you need a DBMS with a good optimizer and good transaction control.

The learning curve is steep.  But the view from the top is worth the climb.

Comment: I've done some database stuff before, and I know the basics of normalization.  However, I'm trying to transition from 'running queries I just typed in and pasted the results for an answer to a homework assignment' to trying to figure out the best way to make a web-app.  I know stored procedures and the like, the concept of them, but it's different when you're creating it from scratch with no guide around lol